# asp.net noob jquery + runat="server" vs declaring the form with all options

Tags: asp.net

I have a form, when I typed it out like this:

```
<form name="formLogin" id="formLogin" action="index.aspx" method="post">
```

My javascript works, and the source code of the webpage is the same as listed above.

When I type it out like this:

```
<form name="formLogin" id="formLogin" runat="server">
```

My page breaks down.  I am basically working with a third party template and trying to convert it to asp.net.

The source code that is displayed is this:

```
<form id="formLogin" action="index.aspx" method="post">
```

It seems when I use the `runat="server"` option it recreates the form element with no name?  Must I use `runtat="server"` if on .net and want to handle Jquery and Server side validation?

Will I still be able to validate in the code behind page if I do not include the `runat="Server"`?

```
      $(document).ready(function () {     
            onfocus();
            $(".on_off_checkbox").iphoneStyle();
            $('.tip a ').tipsy({gravity: 'sw'});
            $('#login').show().animate({   opacity: 1 }, 2000);
            $('.logo').show().animate({   opacity: 1,top: '30%'}, 800,function(){           
                $('.logo').show().delay(1200).animate({   opacity: 1,top: '0%' }, 300,function(){
                    $('.formLogin').animate({   opacity: 1,left: '0' }, 300);
                    $('.userbox').animate({ opacity: 0 }, 200).hide();
                 });        
            })  
        }); 

        $('.userload').click(function(e){
            $('.formLogin').animate({   opacity: 1,left: '0' }, 300);               
              $('.userbox').animate({ opacity: 0 }, 200,function(){
                  $('.userbox').hide();             
               });
        });

    $('#but_login').click(function(e){              
          if(document.formLogin.username.value == "" || document.formLogin.password.value == "") // BREAKS HERE
          {
              showError("Please Input Username / Password");
              $('.inner').jrumble({ x: 4,y: 0,rotation: 0 });   
              $('.inner').trigger('startRumble');
              setTimeout('$(".inner").trigger("stopRumble")',500);
              setTimeout('hideTop()',5000);
              return false;
          }     
         hideTop();
         loading('Checking',1);     
         setTimeout( "unloading()", 2000 );
         setTimeout( "Login()", 2500 );
    }); 

function Login(){
    $("#login").animate({   opacity: 1,top: '49%' }, 200,function(){
         $('.userbox').show().animate({ opacity: 1 }, 500);
            $("#login").animate({   opacity: 0,top: '60%' }, 500,function(){
                $(this).fadeOut(200,function(){
                  $(".text_success").slideDown();
                  $("#successLogin").animate({opacity: 1,height: "200px"},500);                  
                });                           
             }) 
     }) 
    setTimeout( "window.location.href='dashboard.html'", 3000 );
}

$('#alertMessage').click(function(){
    hideTop();
});

function showError(str){
    $('#alertMessage').addClass('error').html(str).stop(true,true).show().animate({ opacity: 1,right: '0'}, 500);   

}

function showSuccess(str){
    $('#alertMessage').removeClass('error').html(str).stop(true,true).show().animate({ opacity: 1,right: '0'}, 500);    
}

function onfocus(){
                if($(window).width()>480) {                   
                        $('.tip input').tipsy({ trigger: 'focus', gravity: 'w' ,live: true});
                }else{
                      $('.tip input').tipsy("hide");
                }
}

function hideTop(){
    $('#alertMessage').animate({ opacity: 0,right: '-20'}, 500,function(){ $(this).hide(); });  
}   

function loading(name,overlay) {  
      $('body').append('<div id="overlay"></div><div id="preloader">'+name+'..</div>');
              if(overlay==1){
                $('#overlay').css('opacity',0.1).fadeIn(function(){  $('#preloader').fadeIn();  });
                return  false;
         }
      $('#preloader').fadeIn();   
 }

 function unloading() {  
        $('#preloader').fadeOut('fast',function(){ $('#overlay').fadeOut(); });
 }
```

Comment: Can you post an example of the jQuery code that stops working when you change to using `runat='server'`?

Comment: Do you have multiple forms on the page? ASP.NET does not all this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163736.aspx#S4

Comment: This login page is all under one form.  @TimSchmelter

Comment: @JamesWilson - This is more then likely an issue with the ID for the form / any controls.  Can you post more details such as the jquery code so we can help.

Comment: @TLS it breaks down on this line of code. `if(document.formLogin.username.value == "" || document.formLogin.password.value == "")`  It says that `document.formLogin is undefined` but only says that when i use runat=server

Comment: Well, that's interesting.  You've mixed "traditional" JavaScript methods for accessing `input` fields with jQuery.  You might be able to resolve the issues just by being consistent with the use of jQuery.

Comment: @JamesWilson change that line by using `$('ID').val` you've got a mix of js and jquery.

Comment: I changed it to this and it works just fine. `if($('#username_id').val() == "" || $('#password').val() == "")`  I'm using a template so not sure why they mixed jquery and javascript in that instance.

Comment: I cringe when I see checks for "" but at the end of the day it works.  I don't know why I cringe - there is nothing wrong with it.  It might be because I am in favor of constants such as String.Empty in C# for example.  Glad you got it working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you dont `runat=Server` you won't be able to access the actual form / any control not marked runat=server in code behind (server side).  Please post your jquery code and I can edit this answer if I see something odd.

Use `$("#username").val().length` and the same for your password to see if a name / password exists.  You have a mixup of both js and jquery making it all the more difficult to find the culprit.

`if($("#username").val().length == 0 && $("#password").val().length == 0)`

```
  //enter here if one is missing
```

Comment: Any idea why this breaks everything when I add runat="server"?  I remove it and my jquery validates, I add it and it pretends the form doesn't exist.

Comment: @JamesWilson you need to post all the details.  What does your jquery do?  I don't see any reason why this would breakdown.

Comment: Could have something to do with your jQuery selectors and the ID's of the controls that are generated when you apply the runat="server" tag. You don't have enough of your code for us to tell.